# « L'avantage, c'est les stylos » ou « L'avantage, ce sont les stylos » ?

Tags: grammaire, pluriel, accord

En français parlé, on entend bien souvent des phrases agencées comme celle-ci :

> L'avantage, c'est les stylos.

Je ne suis pas encore puriste, mais à mon avis, c'est faux. Je dirais plutôt :

> L'avantage, **ce sont** les stylos.

Ne doit-on pas accorder le verbe être dont le sujet est *ce* avec le complément d'objet, en l'occurrence *les stylos* ? Après tout, ce ne serait malheureusement pas la première des fautes courantes dans le français parlé.

Comment: J'adore le « pas encore » puriste.

Comment: Utilisons le français du marketing : « L'avantage : les stylos. »

Comment: Utilisons le français du tennis : « Avantage Stylo »

Comment: Je préfère l'usage du pluriel, mais ce ne suis que moi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comme le dit Joubarc, les choses sont plus complexes qu'il n'y paraît de premier abord. Voici un extrait tiré de la *Grammaire Larousse du français contemporain* :

> Jusqu'au XVIe siècle, on disait : *ce suis je*, *ce es tu*, *ce est il*, *ce sommes-nous*, *ce estes-vous*, *ce sont ils*. Le verbe s'accordait avec le sujet *postposé*. Mais à la 3e personne, à côté de *ce est il*, s'est développé, avec emploi du pronom accentué, *ce est lui* = *c'est lui* ; et, par analogie, *c'est vous*, *c'est nous*...  Dans ces tournures, le verbe semble s'accorder avec CE.  On s'achemine vers l'invariabilité du groupe : *c'est*.  Cependant, au XVIIe siècle, les grammairiens ont admis que l'ont dise CE SONT EUX, à côté de C'EST EUX.

Pour moi (mais je ne suis pas une autorité !) *Ce sont des jouets*  et  *C'est des jouets* se disent  et sont tout aussi corrects.

Mais peut-être pourait-on y voir une différence de sens ? Quand je dis *Ce sont des jouets*, je peux penser à chaque jouet pris séparément ; quand je dis *C'est des jouets* je peux penser à un tout (un tas, un carton, une étagère.. un ensemble de jouets).

---

EDIT

Marcel Cohen  écrivait en 1947 dans un paragraphe consacré aux pronoms personnels dans son *Histoire d'une langue le français* :

> l'expression composée du démonstratif et du verbe *être* : le verbe y est depuis longtemps partiellement figé, n'ayant plus que la troisième personne. L'usage tenu n'est pas fixé pour le pluriel : *c'est eux* et *ce sont eux* (*c'est eux que je veux*,  *ce sont eux que je vois là-bas*) ; mais l'usage populaire ne connait que *c'est* invariable.

Comment: À mon avis, il aurait été bien plus simple de conserver les règles valables jusqu'à XVIe. Ce suis-je, c'es tu, etc., me parait plus logique. Matheux, je cherche un minimum de logique dans le français.

Comment: Les langues ne suivent pas la logique, mais l'usage. Rassure-toi, je peux comprendre ton désir de rationnalisation, et beaucoup de personnes aiment aussi les mathématiques et la logique ici, mais vouloir les "déterritorialiser" comme ça est parfois une périlleuse entreprise...

Answer (score 4):

Ici, le sujet est *l'avantage*, pas *les stylos*, et le verbe s'accorde avec le sujet. *Les stylos* est complément d'objet direct.

> L'avantage, c'est (quoi ?) les stylos.

Ou encore:

> L'enfer, c'est les autres. ([Sartre](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huis_clos_%28th%C3%A9%C3%A2tre%29#R.C3.A9sum.C3.A9))

Comment: Je connaissais cette citation de Sartre, et je pense, à tord visiblement, qu'il y avait une erreur volontaire et ironique!

Ainsi, écrit-on "Ce sont des jouets" ou "C'est des jouets"? À quoi est sensé se référer le sujet *ce*?

Comment: Shlublu, tu as des références ? J'ai la désgréable impression qu'on pourrait aussi facilement écrire la réponse diamétralement opposée, sans pour autant avoir plus de certitude. D'accord, il y a la citation de Sartre, mais ça me laisse sur ma faim.

Comment: Je comprends. Je me suis référé aux règles d'accord verbe/sujet telles que l'on peut les trouver un peu partout, et aux règles régissant le COD : http://www.aidenet.eu/analyse12.htm - Le point, à mon sens, c'est que dire "C'est des chênes." est familier, "ce" (enfin, "c'") se référant à un pluriel (les chênes). Par contre, lorsque l'on dit "l'avantage, c'est ...", "c'" concerne alors l'avantage - singulier, et qu'importe alors que le COD soit un pluriel. D'où "l'avantage, c'est ..." et "les avantages, ce sont ..." (et qu'importe que cette phrase ait peu de sens pourvu qu'elle soit correcte).

Answer (score 4):

Comme je n'ai pas les livres nécessaires, les citations suivantes sont tirées d'un [autre forum](http://www.languefrancaise.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=6161), et par souci d'honnêteté je me dois de préciser que je n'ai pas tout lu. (Et encore,  je n'ai pris que le premier lien d'une [longue série](http://www.google.be/search?q=l%27enfer+c%27est+les+autres+grammaire).)

Le [Grevisse](http://www.languefrancaise.net/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=58254#p58254) dit :

> Le verbe [être] suivi d'un nom (ou d'un pronom autre qu'un pronom personnel) pluriel s'accorde généralement avec celui-ci.
>   Toutefois, le singulier, qui est l'usage ordinaire de la langue parlée non soignée, n'est pas tellement rare dans l'écrit, soit parce que l'auteur veut reproduire cet usage populaire, soit parce qu'il se réfère à la tradition classique.
>   Le singulier est particulièrement fréquent dans certains cas :
>   [...]
>   - lorsque le pronom ce reprend un nom ou un pronom singuliers qui précèdent : Le catholicisme en France, c'est les congrégations.

Il y a aussi une citation de [Pièges et difficultés de la langue française](http://www.languefrancaise.net/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=58251#p58251) :

> Le verbe être doit s'employer au pluriel quand ce + être est suivi d'un nom pluriel :   > *Voyez ces arbres, ce sont des chênes.*
>   La forme *C'est des chênes* appartient au langage familier.

La réponse est donc plus complexe qu'il n'y paraît de premier abord, mais dans ce cas-ci, je penche plutôt pour la forme « L'avantage, ce sont les stylos. », d'autant plus que ce sont bien les stylos qui sont un avantage, et pas l'avantage qui est des stylos (qui à mon avis ne veut rien dire). Pour moi, les stylos sont clairement le sujet.

Pour résumer : Le sujet, ce sont les stylos.

Comment: Diamétralement opposés nous sommes, sur cette question. Les stylos seraient sujet de la phrase "Ce sont les stylos qui constituent un avantage" du fait de ce à quoi "ce" fait référence - et "un avantage" serait alors COD. Mais "L'avantage" est bien sujet de la phrase "L'avantage, c'est les stylos", tandis que "les stylos" y sont COD. Dans cette dernière, "c'est" se réfère au sujet : l'avantage. Qu'importe le manque de sens de la phrase, ce n'en est pas moins une phrase correcte. Si nous préférons une phrase exemple ayant du sens, nous pouvons utiliser celle de Sartre.

Comment: Je reste convaincu que les stylos sont un avantage et le sujet. Mais la meilleure réponse, _ce sont_ les votes qui la détermineront.

Comment: Joli, j'adhère :)

Comment: Ah, mais dans cette dernière phrase de ta part nous sommes dans un cas différent ! Dans "La meilleure réponse, ce sont les votes qui la détermineront", "Ce" fait révérence aux votes, et non à la meilleure réponse. C'est donc bien le pluriel qui s'impose.

Comment: Donc quoi, tu n'es plus qu'à moitié d'accord avec toi-même ?

Comment: Au contraire, cela renforce mon opinion: la phrase où tu as utilisé un pluriel ne correspond pas au cas sujet de la question.

Comment: Après tout, le problème, *c'est/ce sont* les difficultés de la langue française! Attendons que quelques votes viennent départager davantage les réponses.

Comment: D'après [http://www.languefrancaise.net/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=6405#p6405] (l'administrateur du forum de languefrançaise.net) qui cite *l'ABC de la langue française*, "Le verbe être ayant pour sujet le pronom CE se met ordinairement au pluriel quand l'attribut est un nom pluriel ou un pronom de la 3e personne du pluriel, non précédés d'une préposition." Nous aurions trouvés la réponse si seulement cet extrait ne précisait pas *ordinairement*. On avance tout de même, merci encore de vos réponses à tous!

Comment: ChrisR, je dirais "le problème, c'est les difficultés de la langue française", ou bien "le problème, ce sont les difficultés de la langue française qui le posent". Question de sujet. Sérieusement, j'aimerais bien que l'on trouve quelqu'un qui soit capable de trancher.